The reverse implication for $(f(A))^c \subset f(A^c)$ for every $A \subset X$ if $f$ is surjective.
Given a map of sets $f: X \to Y$, I was able to prove that for any subset $A \subset X$, if $f$ is surjective, then $(f(A))^c \subset f(A^c)$. I am trying to figure out whether the reverse implication holds. In particular, if I can say that:

If $(f(A))^c \subset f(A^c)$ for every subset $A$ of $X$, then $f$ is surjective.

Or if I can make only a weaker statement that this is true provided that $(f(A))^c \subset f(A^c)$ for some fixed, particular subset $A$. My attempt at the stronger statement appears somewhat shaky, but it is as follows.

Suppose that $(f(A))^c) \subset f(A^c)$ for every subset $A$ of $X$. Let $y \in Y$ and $A \subset X$ be arbitrary. Then either $y \in f(A)$ or $y \not \in f(A)$. If $y \in f(A)$, then $y$ has a preimage in $X$ and we're done. If $y \not \in f(A)$, then $y \in (f(A))^c$. But $(f(A))^c) \subset f(A^c)$, so $y \in f(A^c)$, and there $y$ has a preimage in $A^c$. So $f$ is surjective.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback on both the hypothesized statement and my attempt at proving it.

The proof shows that it is enough for $(f(A))^c \subset f(A^c)$ to hold for some subset $A$ of $X$ to conclude that $f$ is surjective (and the containment, assumed true for at least one subset of $X$, must in fact be true for every subset of $X$).

Your proof is correct, and for the proof of the statement

If $(f(A))^{\mathrm c}\subset f(A^{\mathrm c})$ for every subset $A$ of $X$, then $f$ is surjective.

Just take $A=X$, then $f(X)^{\mathrm c}\subset f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, and so $f(X)$ must be $Y$.
Hope this helps. :)
